# conditionally highlighting values in python based on additional columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
names=pd.Dataframe({'name': ['ben','adam','steve'],
'name1':['ben1','adam1','steve1'],
'name2':['ben2','adam2','steve2'],
'name3':['ben3','adam3','steve3'],
'name1_comp':[1,0,1],
'name2_comp':[0,1,1],
'name3_comp':[0,1,1]}]
```

I would like an output of :

```
names=pd.Dataframe({'name': ['ben','adam','steve'],
'name1':['ben1','adam1','steve1'],
'name2':['ben2','adam2','steve2'],
'name3':['ben3','adam3','steve3']}]
```

with ben1, adam2, adam3, steve1,steve2,steve3 highlighted.
This will be written into excel afterwards.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: The names you want to be highlighted do not match the boolean table provided (ben3 should not be highlighted, should it?)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question

Comment: so, "highlighting" here means the cells should be coloured differently in the exported excel file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
names2 = names.filter(like='_comp').rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-5])

def hl(df):
    style = 'background-color: yellow'
    return np.where(names2.reindex_like(df).eq(1), style, '')

names.filter(regex=r'(?<!_comp)$').style.apply(hl, axis=None)
```

output:

[image]

For the full DataFrame:

```
def hl(df):
    style = 'background-color: yellow'
    df2 = df.filter(like='_comp').rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-5]).reindex_like(df)
    return np.where(df2.eq(1), style, '')

names.style.apply(hl, axis=None)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: After using your code, I get an error saying that "Function <function hl at 0x7f16c24da550> must return a dataFrame when passed to 'Styler.apply' with axis=None"

Comment: which pandas version do you have? Try: `names2.reindex_like(df).eq(1).map({True: style, False: ''})`/`return df2.eq(1).map({True: style, False: ''})`

Comment: I am using python 3 on a jupyter notebook. The fix you suggested doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I'm talking about the **pandas** version: `pd.__version__`

Comment: Oops sorry misread your comment. 1.0.5

Comment: try to update, this is a quite old version (2020)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245419/discussion-between-aasseeedd-and-mozway).